# TypeError: Comments is undefined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, postgresql, production-environment

I'd like to submit new comments via AJAX using JavaScript and rails-ujs in my Rails 5.1.4 app running in the production environment, database Postgres 11 (without the deployment)

(This works in the development environment)

But when I try to post a new comment, my view doesn't change and in my `web-console` i receive this:

`TypeError: Comments is undefined` referencing line 9 in my create.js.erb file

***create.js.erb***

```
var comment = {
  'body': '<%= @comment.body %>',
  'commenter': '<%= @comment.user.name %> ',
  'commenterId': '<%= @comment.user.id %> ',
  'avatar': '<%= @comment.user.avatar %> ',
  'datetime': '<%= @comment.created_at.strftime('on %e %b %Y at %H:%M') %>',
};

Comments.displayComment(comment);     # <~ Line causing the error

console.log("Comment", comment);
```

extracted ***comments.js***

```
Comments = {};

Comments.displayComment = function(comment) {

  var commentBlock = document.createElement('blockquote');
  commentBlock.className = 'blockquote';

  ...
  ...
  ...

  var comments = document.getElementById('commentList');
  comments.appendChild(commentBlock);
};
```

extracted ***show view*** (set remote: true)

```
<%= form_for([@tip, @tip.comments.build], remote: true) do |form| %>
```

I've been checking other post looking for similar answers, but no luck yet.
Also, I've tried declaring a variable 'Comments' in the `create.js.erb` file, but received the same error.

I think I'm missing something in my javascript, but I not sure what. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your comments.js file is not being uploaded to your production server, show a simple alert() in comments.js file and then upload to production server and check whether that alert is being shown.

Comment: @SaqibShahzad In fact, I did place an `alert()` in comments.js and it does not pop up on the browser. Then, how to ensure that `comments.js` is rendered when I reload the production server?

Comment: Comments.addComment(comment);   - In this line, what is Comments, i see variable defined in `comments.js`. why you need that variable. i don't see any ample use of it. you can write methods directly. Error is saying that in that line Comments is undefined as `comments.js` didnt load , did you add that in application.js?

Comment: @Hemali In this case Comments is an empty object, and yes the defined variable might be unnecessary, as initially, I called the _displayComment_ function directly in _create.js.erb_ like this: `Comments.displayComment(comment);`, but it didn't work either. In application.js I included `//= require_tree .`. Do I need to include comments.js too?

Comment: If it is not being loaded in your production, then make sure to compile your assets before pushing to production. you can run "bundle exec rake assets:precompile" and then push to production

Comment: are you using Heroku or some other service for production?

Comment: @SaqibShahzad I used that command to re-precompile my assets, but still, it doesn't load the commenst.js file. By the way, I'm only running the production environment locally. And once this works, then I'll use Heroku for deployment. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the steps I followed to solve it:

In my `production.log`, I found a conflict with a `bootstrap.js` file. So, I deleted it beforehand.

1. **Remove all of the files in the `public/assets` folder**. *(Remove the previous precompilations)*
2. **Empty the `/my_rails_app/tmp` folder**. *(To clear temporary files created by rails)*
3. **Run** `RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile`. *(To precompile my assets pipeline)*
4. **Run** `RAILS_ENV=production rails server` on your `Terminal`(`bash/shell`). Or just **Run** `./run-my-production.sh` file *(To restart the server in the production environment)*. Here an example of the [run-production.sh](https://gist.github.com/dangerrg/8cc11704bfad06dc7a431196f9e954a6) file
5. Visit your https://localhost:3000 and try again: my AJAX call is working properly as expected.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Dan, it seems like your asset pipeline encounters an issue while precompiling your assets. I suggest that you check the output in the console while running the app in development mode looking for an error with javascript files.
Then empty your `tmp` folder before running the `precompile` command again.
It helps me solve the problem.

Comment: In this case, it should be running the app in the "production" environment instead, because the in "development" environment it's not necessary the precompilation.